# Search string for a certain prefix, and keep the last part using regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a regex problem.

In google analytics, I want to add a filter that re-writers certain parts of URLs, and keeps only the last part of them.

My problem is that in these URLs, I have the character `-`

This is an example :

```
/on/wordsearched.store/sites-eu-site/section_1/default
```

Here, i'm supposed to keep `default`

As you can see, the URL contains dashes `-`

So when I use the following regex :

```
[^/on/wordsearched.store/sites\-eu\-site/section_1](.*)
```

It should give me the string `default`

Instead, it gives me `fault`

It cuts off the first 2 characters of the word. Anyone knows the reason?

I tried many solutions that didn't work exactly as I wanted :

`[^/]+$` : This takes all URLs but I only want the URLs that start with the prefix above.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: is it that you want to match only the part after the last forward-slash?

Comment: @SanV I want to match the last part after the string `/on/wordsearched.store/sites-eu-site/section_1/`

Comment: see my answer below for regex and .split() option to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Will do a noncapture match for `wordsearched` and get the last `/` value

```
(?:wordsearched.*)\/(?<last>.*$)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The part with `section` is a variable, the only constant is the part with `wordsearched`

Comment: @HelpASisterOut oh in that case I've altered the regex to match by wordsearched and get by the last value in the string but you do have to refer to the target value by the group name `last`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you use a negated character class starting with `^` inside the square brackets which matches not what is listed.

The first match from that character class is the `f`. After that match you capture all characters except a newline in a capturing group given you `ault`. So the whole match is `fault`

[See the regex match](https://regex101.com/r/oSNM4S/1)

I think you meant to match default in the first capturing group where the `^` now means and anchor to assert the start of the string.

```
^\/on/wordsearched\.store\/sites-eu-site\/section_1\/(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oSNM4S/2)

Comment: Thank you. For some reason this regex on Google Analytics filter kept me the FIrst part of the URL and deleted the last part (the one i want). For this `/on/wordsearched.store/sites-eu-site/section_1/default` it returned `/on/wordsearched.store/sites-eu-site/section_1/` instead of `default`

Comment: @HelpASisterOut Try switching it around `^(\/on/wordsearched\.store\/sites-eu-site\/section_1\/).*` https://regex101.com/r/oSNM4S/3

Answer (score 0):

This matches any word characters** after the last forward-slash:

```
(?<=\/)[\w]*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iaXmq1/1)

** any letter, digit or underscore, equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]

if google-analytics lets you use python code, you could simply use .split() as follows:

```
S = '/on/wordsearched.store/sites-eu-site/section_1/default'
S.split('/')[-1]  ## Output:  'default'
```